# Paypal Rest API payment verification serverside

Tags: php, paypal, payment, verification

I have setup the payment on my server with paypal, after doing some check it redirects the user to paypal payment page which in turn redirect user to my website with one custom parameter 'approved'='ok' or 'nok'. Apart from this i get 3 more field in GET params i.e. payment-id, payerid and token on success. i want to verify whether these parameter are coming from paypal and check the payment status whether user has really paid the amount on server side only.

Will anybody help. Ready to provide more info.

My return url look like:
http://localhost/test/payment.php?approved=ok&paymentId=PAY-6P3424788A4717248KYR6EPA&token=EC-0V6779052Y720131T&PayerID=JWTZXBN9AEBMC

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see transaction status after post parameters to paypal and they return the response error or success message. Here is one complete example of the payment process with recurring and after that ordinary payment:

```
// Parameters for SetExpressCheckout, which will be sent to PayPal

$padata['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0']   = 'Product description';
$padata['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0']   = $padata['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0'] . 
' $'.$product->price.'/month';
$padata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0']         = $padata['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0'] . 
' $'.$product->price.'/month';
$padata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL']        = 'http://site_url/paypal/ipn';
$padata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC']            = $product->name;
$padata['RETURNURL']                        = 'http://site_url/paypal/returnurl';
$padata['CANCELURL']                        = 'http://site_url/paypal/cancelurl';

$padata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE']    = 'USD';
$padata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION']   = 'SALE';
$padata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT'] = $product->price;
$padata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT']      = $product->price;
$padata['L_BILLINGTYPE0']            = 'RecurringPayments';
$padata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0']  = $product->name;
$padata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0']= '322';
$padata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0']  = '1';
$padata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0']   = $product->price;


$paypal_data            = http_build_query($padata);
$httpParsedResponseAr   = $this->PPHttpPost('SetExpressCheckout', $paypal_data);

//Respond according to message we receive from Paypal
if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])){

    //Redirect user to PayPal store with Token received.
    $paypalurl ='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token='.$httpParsedResponseAr["TOKEN"].'';
    header('Location: '.$paypalurl);

}else{
    echo 'Error : '.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]).'';


}
```

Page returnurl:

```
$hosteddata['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0']   = 'Recurring Description';
$hosteddata['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0']    = $hosteddata['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0'] . ' $'.$pr->price.'/month';
$hosteddata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0']         = $pr->name;
$hosteddata['PROFILEREFERENCE']                    = $GetExpressCheckoutDetails['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0'];
$hosteddata['PROFILESTARTDATE']                 = date('Y-m-d') . 'T' . date('H:i:s').'Z';
$hosteddata['SUBSCRIBERNAME']                    = $GetExpressCheckoutDetails['FIRSTNAME'] . ' ' . $GetExpressCheckoutDetails['LASTNAME'];
$hosteddata['TOKEN']                          = urlencode($_POST['token']);
$hosteddata['DESC']                               = $hosteddata['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0'];
$hosteddata['AMT']                             = $pr->price;
$hosteddata['BILLINGPERIOD']                  = 'Month';
$hosteddata['BILLINGFREQUENCY']                  = '1';
$hosteddata['TOTALBILLINGCYCLES']                = '12';
$hosteddata['REGULARTOTALBILLINGCYCLES']        = '1';
$hosteddata['VERSION']                           = '74.0';
$hosteddata['MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS']              = '1';
$hosteddata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0']           = '1';
$hosteddata['L_BILLINGTYPE0']                    = 'RecurringPayments';
$hosteddata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0']  = 'Digital';
$hosteddata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0']         = $pr->price;
$hosteddata['INITAMT']                            = $pr->price;
$hosteddata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0']     = $pr->id;
$hosteddata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL']        = 'http://site_url/paypal/ipn';


$paypal_data = http_build_query($hosteddata);
$hosted_saas_response = $this->PPHttpPost('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile', $paypal_data);
```

**I used a separate method to post parameters to paypal**

```
private function PPHttpPost( $methodName_, $nvpStr_ ) {

$api_username   = 'yourpaypal@email.com';
$api_password   = 'QWEQWEWQEQWEQEQWE';
$api_signature   = 'WQEQWEQWEQWEWQEQWEQWEQWEQWEQWE.cT';
$api_endpoint    = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
$version     = '124.0';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 
$nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$api_password&USER=$api_username&SIGNATURE=$api_signature&$nvpStr_";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);
$httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$httpResponse) {
        exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
}

    // Extract the response details.
    $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

    $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
    foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
        $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
        if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
            $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
         }
    }

    if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {

        exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $api_endpoint.");

    }

    return $httpParsedResponseAr;

}
```

**Parameters for SetExpressCheckout for one time ordinary payment:**

```
// Parameters for SetExpressCheckout for one time ordinary payment
$padata['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0']    = 'Product descriptuion;
$padata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0']            = $padata['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0'];
$padata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL']      = 'http://siteurl.com/paypal/ipn';
$padata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC']         = $padata['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0'];
$padata['RETURNURL']                       = 'http://siteurl.com/paypal/returnToDownload';
$padata['CANCELURL']                        = 'http://siteurl.com/paypal/cancelurl';

$padata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE']    = 'USD';
$padata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION']  = 'SALE';
$padata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT']           = $product->price;
$padata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT']              = $product->price;
$padata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0']          = $product->price;

$padata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0']       = 'verification_id#@@#!@#!@#@!!@#ASDASD';
$padata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0']            = '1';
$padata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0']           = $product->price;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response pavel, I hope you understood the problem. I have already sent all details to paypal and user has paid and return to my website. with those 3 extra params appended in GET url, what i really want is to check that the parameters are set by paypal not by user (just to ensure i am not being fooled by hijackers). I have come across PDT and IPN which i really don't want' to use. I want to move ahead with only those 3 params. More input from you will be very appreciated. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Understood finally, at the position where i am standing i.e. i have all those 3 params. i didn't actually execute the payment all i got is token and payerid to execute it. still have to run your function PPHttpPost to complete the process with DoExpressCheckoutPayment only then i will geth all the responses i.e. ACK=success or failure and CHECKOUTSTATUS=PaymentActionCompleted. Literally saved my day. Thanks pavel.

Comment: And thanks again for restoring my faith in stackoverflow :)

Comment: No problem ... you WELCOME  :)